# Is it "first-degree-murder charges" or "first-degree murder charges"?

Tags: punctuation

Is it "first-degree-murder charges" or "first-degree murder charges"?

Is " first-degree-murder" bundled together to modify "charges"? Or is 
"first-degree" bundled together to modify "murder charges"?

Or are both technically correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Are these all homework questions?

Comment: Homework questions??? Hell, no, goddamnit! I ask a question out of curiosity and you fucking assume it's a homework question????

Comment: Overreactions like that to an understandable query (not necessarily anything personal, but a lot of the questions asked recently have read like something you'd be assigned as a homework assignment) probably don't help your case any, or encourage anyone to help you answer the question.